# Why flutter UI lags when soft keyboard appears?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using flutter's latest version to create a bottom model sheet with a text field which is auto focused, so as soon as I click the button to show that bottom model the UI lags while soft keyboard appears. I've tried setting the following property to false, but still no luck.

```
Scaffold(
...
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
)
```

Here's the code bottom sheet is being called:

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () async {
      showModalBottomSheet(
          isScrollControlled: true,
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => const TaskBottomSheet());
          }),
```

There's no lag until I make the soft keyboard appear in the screen. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to run it in the profile or release mode? Flutter optimizes your app in these two modes.

```
flutter run --profile or flutter run --release
```